# Simplifing an expression with fractional powers and square roots

Tags: simplifying-expressions

I want to simplify this expression to get 1:

```
In[1]:= $Assumptions = {R > 0, A > 0, t > 0, d > 0, v > 0, L > 0};
FullSimplify[((t v^2 + L Sqrt[(2 d)/t + v^2]) (t^(3/2) v^2 + 
     2 L Sqrt[2 d + t v^2]))/((t v^2 + 
     2 L Sqrt[(2 d)/t + v^2]) (t^(3/2) v^2 + L Sqrt[2 d + t v^2]))]

Out[2]= ((t v^2 + L Sqrt[(2 d)/t + v^2]) (t^(3/2) v^2 + 
  2 L Sqrt[2 d + t v^2]))/((t v^2 + 
  2 L Sqrt[(2 d)/t + v^2]) (t^(3/2) v^2 + L Sqrt[2 d + t v^2]))
```

I also tried *Refine*, *TrigFactor* and *Expand*, but it didn't work as well. Is there any command for this?

Comment: `FullSimplify[... , TransformationFunctions -> {Automatic, PowerExpand}]`

Comment: Or note that `Numerator[expr] == Denominator[expr] // FullSimplify` evaluates to `True`

Comment: Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
expr = ((t v^2 + L Sqrt[(2 d)/t + v^2]) (t^(3/2) v^2 + 
       2 L Sqrt[2 d + t v^2]))/((t v^2 + 
       2 L Sqrt[(2 d)/t + v^2]) (t^(3/2) v^2 + L Sqrt[2 d + t v^2]));

expr /. Sqrt[(2 d)/t + v^2] :> 1/Sqrt[t] Sqrt[2 d + t v^2] // Simplify

(*  1  *)
```

Have fun!